# Convert Python List Comprehension to C#

Tags: python, c#, linq, list-comprehension

How can I convert this python code to C#

```
points = [] 
for i in range(0, len(points_seq), n): 
    points.append(points_seq[i:i + n])
```

Not sure on how to convert it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case of .Net 6+ you can use [Chunk()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0) *Linq* method:

```
  // or List<int> points_seq =
  int[] points_seq = ...
  int n = ...

  ...

  var points = points_seq
    .Chunk(n)
    .ToList(); // if you want List<int[]>, .ToArray() for int[][]
```

If you have previous versions of .Net you can implement the same with a help of `GroupBy`:

```
  var points = points_seq
    .Select((value, i) => (value : value, i : i))
    .GroupBy(item => item.i / n, item => item.value)
    .Select(g => g.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```